# ExactlyOne extension method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, linq, extension-methods

I often find in codebases something on the order of `if (sprockets.Count() > 0)` which is easily replaced with LINQ's `if (sprockets.Any())`. This keeps the entirety of `sprockets` from having to be iterated over completely (to get the count) then comparing to zero. Further, the business logic often reads something like "if there are any sprockets, inform the user of the subtotal". I *also* often see similar logic for exactly one of something: `if (sprockets.Count() == 1)` which doesn't have an easy, low-cost LINQ alternative. So I've created one here:

```
public static bool ExactlyOne<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    }

    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        return enumerator.MoveNext() && !enumerator.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

Usage is `if (sprockets.ExactlyOne())` Here are unit tests. There is one helper method called `Infinite()` which is a never-ending enumerable, which will baffle `sprockets.Count()`, but not `sprockets.ExactlyOne()`:

```
[TestClass]
public sealed class ExactlyOneTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
    public void TestNull()
    {
        int[] nullArray = null;

        Assert.IsFalse(nullArray.ExactlyOne());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestZero()
    {
        int[] zero = Array.Empty<int>();

        Assert.IsFalse(zero.ExactlyOne());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestOne()
    {
        int[] one = { 1 };

        Assert.IsTrue(one.ExactlyOne());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestTwo()
    {
        int[] two = { 1, 2 };

        Assert.IsFalse(two.ExactlyOne());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestInfinite()
    {
        IEnumerable<int> infinite = Infinite();

        Assert.IsFalse(infinite.ExactlyOne());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> Infinite()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Looking for overall review - is the code readable, maintainable, performant. Do the tests cover the expected cases or are there more to consider?

Comment: This discards the element. Have you considered designs that preserve the element, but also tell you if it's the only one?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `SingleOrDefault()` in such cases? Or `Single()` if there has to be a value?

Comment: @BCdotWEB SingleOrDefault() throws an exception if there are multiple elements that fulfill the same criteria.

Comment: @MY_G True, but that's what you want IMHO.

Comment: @BCdotWEB @Alexander: if you want the value, use `.First()` instead of `.Any()`. `.Single()` is analagous to `.ExactlyOne()` in that respect.

Comment: Just as a reference F# has an implementation of `ExactlyOne` and it's pretty much what you have: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/6819e1c769269edefcea2263c98f993e90b623e2/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1412

Comment: @Ringil neat! Thanks for pointing that out. Brings me back to my Haskell days in college.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Another option is to create a method _bool TryGetSingle<T>(out T value)_ conform naming and signature conventions of .NET Framework.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Q&A

> Is the code readable?

- `ExactlyOne` states very clearly what the method is supposed to do.
- `source is null` seems odd to me (does that even compile?). I'd prefer `source == null`. (Edit from comments: a topic about [is null vs == null](https://www.gullberg.tk/blog/is-null-versus-null-in-c/))
- `IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator()` can be written as `var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator()`.

---

> Is the code maintainable?

- Since you are looking for a sibling function of `Any<T>()`, I would also include a `ExactlyOne<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate)`.

---

> Is the code performant?

- It does seem so, right? But notice that LINQ is optimized for `IEnumerable<T>` that is also `ICollection<T>`, in which case `Count` is used. Implementations should have an eager implementation of this property. Your method *could* also use this optimization `Count == 1`.
- I actually noticed (in my eyes) unexpected behavior in LINQ: `Count<T>()` is optimized for `ICollection<T>` but `Any<T()` is not. This means you arguably could make a slightly faster implementation than LINQ.
- An in-depth comparison is required to find the most optimized approach. As discussed in the comments, testing the different implementations against a variety of input sources should yield us which method perfoms best under which conditions.

---

> Do the tests cover the expected cases or are there more to consider?

You cover `null`, empty, 1, multiple, early exit on infinite.. but perhaps also test on `ICollection<T>` and custom `IEnumerable<T>` implementations with eager and/or lazy loading.

---

### Reference Source: [LINQ Any vs Count](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs)

```
// not optimized for ICollection<T> (why ??)
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
        if (e.MoveNext()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (predicate(element)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// optimized for ICollection<T>
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    ICollection<TSource> collectionoft = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (collectionoft != null) return collectionoft.Count;
    ICollection collection = source as ICollection;
    if (collection != null) return collection.Count;
    int count = 0;
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
        checked {
            while (e.MoveNext()) count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Just one Q I'd like to address quickly while I'm thinking about it: I did try my hand at implementing `ExactlyOne<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate)` from first principles - it has to loop over the entire enumerable to run the predicate, so it would be functionally identical to `Count<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) == 1`. I suppose it would be orthogonal to implement it as that.

Comment: Good thinking, it might very well be a complete clone of that method. On the other hand, I think it can be optimized with early exit when count > 1

Comment: You're right. I can optimize. I'm going to add an answer just for reference's sake.

Comment: `source is null` - I read about that as well as `source is object` (sorta like `source != null`) on some twitter feed from a noted developer, but the gist of it can be found here: https://www.gullberg.tk/blog/is-null-versus-null-in-c/

Comment: so _is null_ means _ReferenceEquals(null, source)_ then? I did not know this one

Comment: And I just added your suggested `ICollection` optimization using C#7 pattern matching: `if (source is ICollection<TSource> collection) return collection.Count == 1;` before the `using`. Thanks!

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer using Count for ICollection is a pessimization, and you'd better remove it. While Collections, as opposed to general Enumerables, HAVE a specific count of elements, finding it is NOT guaranteed to be a cheap O(1) operation. In most cases it is, and whenever possible it should be, but there's no guarantee, and in some lazy-loading cases there's no practical possibility. BTW this explains a lack of special case for Any() inside LINQ: while Count() can safely assume that the Count property is at least not slower than naive iteration, Any() can't assume that Count is fast.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer take a look at LINQ reference code: a few extension methods, like Single(), have a special case for IList, but not for ICollection. Apparently, Lists are at least expected to have fast access time and count.
https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs

Comment: @IMil It's interesting to see which LINQ methods optimize for which types of collections. I would have hoped to find a great article about it by some microsoft guru.

Comment: @IMil after benchmarking with and without the "pessimization" (I like this neologism), the without version performs better, in even the simple cases where `ICollection` is backed by an array or list. So, nuked it is.

Comment: @IMil Jesse, should I include your test results in my answer to provide insights why Any isn't 'pessimized' while Count is optimized?

Comment: @dfhwze So, using BenchmarkDotNet, version with `ICollection` check gives 7.823us, version without gives **7.725us**, and t3chb0t version gives 7.927us.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Perhaps it's even better if you would make another self answer with comparison of each the provided methods on a variety of input sources (array, list, custom enumerable that yields results, custom enumerable that knows the Count, but uses lazy enumeration, ..).

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer my point is not that a special case for ICollection WILL be slower, but that it MAY be slower for certain implementations of ICollection. If this is your code, and you know which exact concrete classes your projects are likely to use, then it's fine. But LINQ definitely couldn't use this "optimization", because the extension methods work on any user-defined collections, and there's no guarantee that Count works faster than a couple iterator manipulations.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer also it's conceivable that Count is a bit faster, but an extra cast eats all the savings. Anyway, +- 0.1 microsecond is probably just noise.

Comment: I love the answer but i would say the null check is entirely superfluous because as soon the code reaches source.GetEnumerator() the exact same exception is thrown.

Comment: @dfhwze [This blog comes close](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/)

Comment: @Robert the null check is consistent with the API of Linq. Fail early is never a bad thing.

Answer (score 12):

mhmmm... I'm not so sure about this implementation. @dfhwze's points are valid but still, I find it's overengineered.

I prefer chaining these two alraedy available extensions that can do all mentioned *tricks*:

```
return source.Take(2).Count() == 1
```

or with a predicate

```
return source.Where(predicate).Take(2).Count() == 1;
```

Comment: Interesting alternative way of looking at the problem. You got my vote!

Comment: Tossing my vote in because I like the brevity (specifically, the predicate one), but, for a lack of a better term, I'm trying to get the "first principles" of `.Any()` which could have also been written as `return source.Take(1).Count() == 1`.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer I have a similar case with [`SingleOrThrow`](https://github.com/he-dev/reusable/blob/dev/Reusable.Core/src/Extensions/EnumerableExtensions.cs#L271) that I find is super ugly ;-] so I rewrote it with `Take` + `Count` + `ToList` [here](https://github.com/he-dev/reusable/blob/dev/Reusable.Core/src/Extensions/EnumerableExtensions.cs#L311) and now I like it ;-) I wonder that I didn't have this idea earlier haha

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer [`SingleOrDefault`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1213) with a predicate is even so similar to mine that they also use a `swith`. ok, but their solution is really stupid, it'll enumerate the entire collection! :-o I'm shocked: `new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4}.Select(x => x.Dump()).SingleOrDefault(n => true).Dump();` the inner `Dump` will output everything.

Comment: @dfhwze did you know that? `SingleOrDefault` is dangeours when used with a predicate :-\

Comment: @t3chb0t I did not. The more I browse through the reference source of LINQ, to more I realise I should have done it way sooner.

Comment: @t3chb0t I am sure this must be a copy-paste bug from the argument-free overload.  This is a shock indeed!

Comment: @t3chb0t the scary part is, there's likely code dependent on the suboptimal behavior (side effects) so they'll not rework it properly.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer: Exactly. It's been fixed in .net core, but they are hesitant to backport it to the Framework for the exact reason that you mentioned. See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25079 for details.

Answer (score 11):

This is for [dfhwze](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/200620/dfhwze) as per comment:

```
public static bool ExactlyOne<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    }

    IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator;
    
    try
    {
        enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    }
    catch
    {
        enumerator = null;
    }
    
    using (enumerator)
    {
        return enumerator?.MoveNext() == true && enumerator?.MoveNext() != true;
    }
}

public static bool ExactlyOne<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    }

    if (predicate is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
    }

    IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator;
    bool gotOne = false;

    try
    {
        enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    }
    catch
    {
        enumerator = null;
    }
    
    using (enumerator)
    {
        if (enumerator?.MoveNext() != true)
        {
            return false;
        }

        do
        {
            TSource element = enumerator.Current;

            if (!predicate(element))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (gotOne)
            {
                return false;
            }

            gotOne = true;
        }
        while (enumerator.MoveNext());
    }

    return gotOne;
}
```

I have just redone these so that they will be resilient against really bad `IEnumerable<T>` implementations such as these contrived examples:

```
public sealed class BadEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return null;
    }
    
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}


public sealed class WorseEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Rude!");
    }
    
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems as optimized as I can think of. Early exit is the best you can do.

Comment: The predicate should be allowed to not be provided though, no?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon that version is what the original question has. Use them both together.